PdfInfo.Create method lacks meaningful exception
I'm using PdfInfo.Create method to get count of pages for given pdf file. The project is deployed on server, which is handling multiple requests at same time.
All requests are throwing exception at PdfInfo.Create as  :
FailedToExecuteCommand "C:\Projects\gswin64c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT --permit-file-read="C:/Users/Tomas/AppData/Local/Temp/temp.pdf" -sPDFPassword="qwert" -c "(C:/Users/Tomas/AppData/Local/Temp/temp.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"' (1) @ error/ghostscript-private.h/ExecuteGhostscriptCommand/74`
Note : Can reason for error be due to heavy cpu/memory usage on server, since its also running multiple services.
So can anyone please help why is error happening.
When same request is processed on local or other server its giving page count without any error.

Since this works from the shell, this isn't a question about Ghostscript, so I've removed the tag.

Yes server can run 64bit exe.It's failing to execute sometimes don't know why. The exception don't give any proper info except this  : error/ghostscript-private.h/ExecuteGhostscriptCommand/74`
